# How does "would" work?

Tags: word-usage, modal-verbs

Could you tell me what "would" function" here?

Questioner: hello. I've got a doubt concerning a statement to talk about the future: do we say the best student will win a prize or The best student is winning a prize?

Answer: The correct fom here WOULD be "will win". You WOULD say  "is winning" when you are describing the present - i.e. when you are watching the prize-giving ceremony

Answer (score 0):

The word "would" is used because there is an implied condition.

> (If are talking about the future,) the correct form would be "will win".

The situation is considered to be hypothetical, we are not talking about a specific and real future event. This is sometimes called a "type 2 conditional".

There is a difference between, for example, "I play tennis" and "I would play tennis". The first is indicative. It asserts a fact. The second is tentative. It expresses possibility, dependent on some condition.

> I would play tennis (if I owned a racket / if I had the time / if I were younger)

Comment: Thanks, James K. Could you also explain what is meant with the tentative 'would'?